# Why does my Python code write random symbols on the write() function Python 2.7

Tags: python

I have this Python code:

```
f = open("database.txt", "r+")

f.write("Hello!")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

and when I run the code the Idle shows me:  `-t`

But when I see the `database.txt` file this is whats inside:

```
Hello!t   stdouts   #007700t   stderrc         C   s   | |  _  d  |  _ d  S(   N(   R4   R*   t   owin(   R   R4   (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyR   …   s      c         C   s0   |  j  s |  j ƒ  n  |  j  j | | | ƒ d  S(   N(   RP   t   setupR   (   R   R   R   R   (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyR   ‰   s        
c         C   sx   t  |  j ƒ |  _ } | j } x6 |  j j ƒ  D]% \ } } | r/ | j | |  q/ q/ W| j d ƒ |  j j |  _ d  S(   Nt   sel(    R   R4   RP   R   t   tagdefst   itemst
   tag_configuret      tag_raiseR   (   R   RP   R   t   tagt   cnf(    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyRQ   Ž   s     
(   RG   RH   RS   R   R   RQ   (    (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyRK   }   s           (    (     t   Tkintert   idlelib.EditorWindowR   R-   R2   t   idlelibR   R   RK   (    (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyt   <module>   s   
vWindow.pyt   short_title   s    c         C   s   |  j  ƒ  r d Sd Sd  S(   Nt   yest   no(   t    get_saved(   R   (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyt    maybesave   s    t   insertc         C   ss   t  | t ƒ r< y t | t j ƒ } Wq< t k
 r8 q< Xn  |  j j | | | ƒ |  j j | ƒ |  j j  ƒ  d  S(   N(
   t
   isinstancet   strt   unicodeR   t   encodingt   UnicodeErrorR   R   t   seet   update(   R   t   st   tagst   mark(    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyt   write%   s    
c         C   s"   x | D] } |  j  | ƒ q Wd  S(   N(   R   (   R   t   linest   line(    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyt
   writelines2   s    
c         C   s   d  S(   N(    (   R   (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyt   flush6   s    t   Cuts   <<cut>>t   rmenu_check_cutt   Copys   <<copy>>t   rmenu_check_copyt   Pastes    <<paste>>t   rmenu_check_pastes   Go to file/lines   <<goto-file-line>>s   file "([^"]*)", line (\d+)s   ([^\s]+)\((\d+)\)s   ^(\s*\S.*?):\s*(\d+):s   ([^\s]+):\s*(\d+):s   ^\s*(\S.*?):\s*(\d+):c            C   sô   |  j  d  k rQ g  } x- |  j D]" } | j t j | t j ƒ ƒ q W| |  _  n  |  j j d d ƒ } |  j  | ƒ } | sÅ |  j j d d ƒ } |  j  | ƒ } | sÅ t
 j d d d |  j ƒd  Sn  | \ } } |  j j
 | ƒ } | j | ƒ d  S(   Ns   insert linestarts   insert lineends   insert -1line linestarts   insert -1line lineends   No special linesT   The line you point at doesn't look like a valid file name followed by a line number.t   parent(   t   file_line_progst   Nonet   file_line_patst   appendt   ret   compilet
   IGNORECASER   t   gett   _file_line_helpert   tkMessageBoxt     showerrort   flistt   opent   gotoline(     R   t   eventt   lt   patR   t   resultR
   t   linenot   edit(    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyR   N   s(       
c         C   sª   xz |  j  D]k } | j | ƒ } | r
 | j d d ƒ \ } } y t | d ƒ } | j ƒ  PWqu t k
 rq q
 qu Xq
 q
 Wd  Sy | t | ƒ f SWn t k
 r¥ d  SXd  S(   Ni   i   t   r(       R)   t   searcht   groupR5   t   closet   IOErrorR*   t   intt      TypeError(   R   R   t   progt   matchR
   R;   t   f(    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyR1   i   s    


(    (   R"   s   <<cut>>R#   (   R$   s   <<copy>>R%   (   R&   s     <<paste>>R'   N(   NNN(   s   Go to file/lines   <<goto-file-line>>N(   t   __name__t
   __module__t   __doc__R   R   R
   R   R   R    R!   R*   t   rmenu_specsR+   R)   R   R1   (    (    (    s'   C:\Python27\lib\idlelib\OutputWindow.pyR      s*                    
                t   OnDemandOutputWindowc           B   sE   e  Z i i d  d 6d 6i d d 6d 6Z d „  Z d „  Z d „  Z RS(   t   bluet
   fore
```

Comment: Not sure how you're writing in read mode, but try opening the file in write: `f = open("database.txt", "w")`

Comment: was the file empty, before You've written to it?

Comment: yes it was empty

Comment: This is r+ mode: read and write, not read: http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/

Comment: Jkdc   the idle throws this error:  IOError: File not open for reading

Comment: Well that doesn't solve my problem, using w or r as the second parameter of the open() function throws an error

Comment: IDLE is an editor. It doesn't run code. It's the Python interpreter that runs code.

Comment: jpmc26 Yeah it does, f5 ---> Run Module, it appears in idle

Comment: Can anybody explain where that output comes from? I tried it on my machine and I get a lengthy output, too, though not the same but some python source code. `database.txt` is initially empty but after the write and read operation it actually contains all that text that is returned by calling `read`.

Comment: IDLE is not running the code. It's invoking the interpreter and capturing the output. It's typically a good idea to get outside of the IDE and run it manually if you're going to ask an SO question because I guarantee you that other users are going to run it that way. In this case, you absolutely should do so because the garbage output may be from something IDLE is doing to the process.

Comment: Just found that ticket: http://bugs.python.org/issue29817.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
with open("database.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Hello!")

with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

You avoid the need of manually closing the file using the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).
Plus, you read the files once you have written it.
In general, it is better to separate read and write access to the file. Unless you really need to do both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write to your file, then read it, you should:

Open it in write mode (w). That also truncates the file to zero length.

```
f = open("database.txt", "w")
f.write("Hello!")
f.close
```

Then, open it in read mode (r), which positions you at the start of the file:

```
f = open("database.txt", "r")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

Using "r+" puts you in read/write mode, and doesn't truncate the file. So, when you wrote to it, your "Hello!" string overwrote the beginning of the file, leaving the rest untouched.

It is however better to use `with`, as in:

```
with open("database.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("Hello!")
```

So, you don't have to close the file explicitely, and you're sure that it will be done correctly in case some error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It's only 1 possible reason (IMHO) - *the file `database.txt` was not empty before you wrote to it* (in spite of your assertion in your comment).

So your output is `O.K.` There is your string `Hello!` at the start - the rest is *original content of the file*.

So your `f.read()` started read at the actual position (for reading or writing) -  and it was *just after what you wrote*, i. e. after the symbol `!`. So - in your case - it will begin read from `t`.

You may use `f.seek(position)` to *change your actual position* - in your case `f.seek(0)` (to go at the start of the file) *before using* `f.read()`.

So your full code would be:

```
f = open("database.txt", "r+")

    f.write("Hello!")
    f.seek(0)
    print f.read(6)                 # Note 6 as number of bytes to read
    f.close()
```

Comment: No, that's not normal. Slack space is supposed to be hidden by the operating system -- it should not appear to the user.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. Cluster allocation only exists at the file system layer. From the perspective of userspace applications, files have exactly the size they are created as; any extra space that's allocated behind the scenes is not visible to them, and cannot be read.

Comment: @duskwuff You're right, thanks! I'm going to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should open the file the writing rights with 'w' not 'r' to use write fonction.